# Is there an efficient way for creating files from values in a nested list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file

Looking for some insight into a project that I'm working on.

I have a nested list in the form of a csv file. I'm reading it in, and extracting every first position value in the list of lists. Once done, which I have working, I'd like to create a new file based off of a template CSV file of an existing file and over write the current value with the new one from position one. Then I'd like to save it as a file with a unique name perhaps matching a value from the list, and do the same thing again for however many objects are in the length of the list.

Say my list has values:

values = [[1,2,3],[5,2,3],[7,2,3],[8,2,5]]

```
with open('somelocation', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    values = list(reader)
    
    def first_extract(values):
        return (item[0] for item in values)
        
        
    #now have first element of nested list
        
def main():
    print(first_extract(values))
```

The output would be:

[1,5,7,8]

Is there an easier way to accomplish this goal or is it feasible?

Comment: An easier way to read the CSV and extract the first sublist elements? In my opinion: no. There are faster ways using e. g. pandas if your CSV is pretty large.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I had a feeling. Unfortunately, Pandas isn't applicable, but the CSV is only say 50 or so nested list objects. The part that I'm mainly concerned with is developing a solution now then to write to a CSV file at a specific location based off of a "template" then save it and basically loop through the process to create a new file, update, save for each item in the new list.

Comment: These are multiple topics at once. You should try to solve this yourself and if necessary ask for help for a specific issue, showing what you have tried, what doesn't work as expected and explain details, e. g. how that "template CSV" looks like.

Comment: @MichaelButscher yeah, I figured I'd ask with full detail in case anyone has had these issues before or has done something like this, but I could see how it would be hard for others to weigh in with valid responses in regards to the big picture. I guess I'll hold off, refine, and delete this and then revisit. Thanks